# android using external shared library

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am facing issues in using an external shared library in my Android application. I created an Android.mk file as given below:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := MyApp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := myexternallib.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Using ndk-build I am able to generate a local native library and I use this native library in my `System.loadLibrary` method. 
When I run the application I get an error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1486]:  2659 unknown reloc type    19 @      ( 4220)`

On further search I found a link which recommends to build the shared library using the android toolchain. So I used one of the toolchain `arm-eabi-gcc`, which is available in the  `prebuilt/linux_x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin` directory of the android source code, to build my source files. I get an error `arm-eabi-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory`. I also noticed that the toolchain folder does not have a file named `cc1`.

Am I following the right procedure? Is there some other way to reference external shared library in Android code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that you should use Android toolchain.

Android NDK comes with detailed instructions on using its toolcahin: http://source-android.frandroid.com/ndk/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html. If you have specific questions about this document, feel free to ask.